# Highlighting specific table with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have sample tables and checkboxes here on this link. https://jsfiddle.net/q8aub965/

in the example when you click a checkboxAll, all of the tables are highlighted. I' like to highlight only a specific table for each checkboxAll. Tables have unique table ids. How can I achieve this result? Tables are all same. Checkboxes are php generated. Thanks for your time and help!!

(note: if you can offer a solution without checkbox, I am open for this too)

Example checkbox code:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All (for table1)
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="2" class="selector" />2
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="7" class="selector" />7
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="7" class="selector" />7
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried to associate a value to each checkbox and after that reading the selected value from request?

Comment: You need to specify different name id for each all checkbox so you can control for which table is belong

Comment: you mean instead of  name="SelectAll", like  name="SelectAll1" etc.. ? there will be more tables, and checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change you function so it accept 3 parameters:

- check state
- value to check
- table id

The last one could be optional. Then you change your jQuery to accesses only the table (if there was one) and change the cells with the given value.

```
function foo(check, value, table){
  if(table && table != ''){
    table = '#'+table;
  }else{
    table = 'table';
  }

  $(table+' td').each(function(i,e){
    if(($(e).html() == value || '' == value) && check){
      $(e).addClass('highlight');
    }else{
      $(e).removeClass('highlight');
    }
  });
}
```

with this function, you could specify for every checkbox the right function call:

```
foo(true, '2', 'tb1'); //  select all calls with '2' in table 'tb1'
foo(true, '2'); //  select all calls with '2' in all tables
foo(false, '1', 'tb2'); // deleslect all cells in table 'tb2'
```

Just add the following to your html code:

```
<div>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" onclick="foo($(this).is(':checked'), '', 'tb1')" class="all" />All (for table1)</label>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="2" onclick="foo($(this).is(':checked'), '2', 'tb1')" class="selector" />2</label>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="7" onclick="foo($(this).is(':checked'), '7', 'tb1')" class="selector" />7</label>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="7" onclick="foo($(this).is(':checked'), '7', '')" class="selector" />7 in all Tables</label>

  </form>
  // and so on
```

Comment: thanks, Marcus. but I didn't write to jquery code myself. I don't know jquery, just some basics.

Comment: Thanks, Marcus. I will try that. as I see, I need to edit all forms manually, this will be difficult for actual implementation. I guess there doesn't seem be an easy way for this work either. it's a little complicated.